# How do i swap textbox for buttons?

Tags: javascript

i have project that is fake casino where you can bet on matches from hockey and i ran into problem the previous guy had text input where you could put 0,1 or 2 that depends on what team you want to bet on
`out.write("<td class='" + cl + "'><form method=\"post\" action=\"matches.jsp\">Tip: <input type=\"text\" name=\"tip\" size=\"1\" maxlength=\"1\"> Points: <input type=\"text\" name=\"amount\" size=\"6\" maxlength=\"6\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"matchId\" value=\"" + matches.get(i).getMatchId() + "\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Bet\"></form></td>");`
(His code that works fine)

I tried to make it with buttons and came up with this

```
                out.write("<td class='" + cl + "'><form method=\"post\" action=\"matches.jsp\"><br>");
                out.write("<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"tip\" name=\"tip\" value=\"\">");
                out.write("<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('tip').value=\'1\'; highlightButton(this);\" value=\"" + matches.get(i).getFirstPlayer() + "\">");
                out.write("<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('tip').value=\'0\'; highlightButton(this);\" value=\"Draw\">");
                out.write("<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('tip').value=\'2\'; highlightButton(this);\" value=\"" + matches.get(i).getSecondPlayer() + "\"><br>");
                out.write("<input type=\"text\" name=\"amount\" size=\"5\" maxlength=\"5\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"matchId\" value=\"" + matches.get(i).getMatchId() + "\">");
                out.write("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Bet\"><br></form></td>");
                
                out.write("<script>function highlightButton(button) {"
                + "var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('input');"
                + "for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {"
                + "if (buttons[i].type === 'button') {"
                + "buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = '';"
                + "}"
                + "}"
                + "button.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';"
                + "}</script>");
```

But now if there is more matches in for it will always edit the 1st match in the for anyone knows how to help?

Comment: Why are you writing JS using JS? :p